# Status bar style changed from light content to gray color style

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, statusbar

In one of my application, I have set `Translucent` color for `StatusBar`.

In the First 2 screens, it's showing as expected but on 3rd screen, it will change the style of the status bar. It will convert to Gray Translucent.

**Expected Screen sample:**

[image]

**Current Issue:**

[image]

I have done all changes related to show the Light Content Status bar in the application.

**Make appearance of status bar as `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

**Also Add Flag to plist as mention below.**

[image]

But still above issue is occurring in my application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: set [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
in appdelegate.m applicationdidfinishwithOptions

Comment: use Status bar Style in .plist, that should work..

Comment: Make sure that your image view is pinned to the top and not to the statusbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add code like below in your

`AppDelegate` class method `appDidFinishLaunching`

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

Not only this you have to add statusbar style into your info.plist file.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Please check my question i have different problem with screen getting 20PX down due to status bar

Comment: Ok got it if its not work in 3rd screen you need to agin write this appdelegate status bar chnage code agin on that VC's viewWillAppear () method.